# BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 64

Tags: flutter, gradle, aws-amplify, flutteramplify

I wanted to use gradle version 7.5.1 in order to add aws to my flutter project. But it has been constantly showing me an error since I tried to change the gradle version. At first I got warnings in vs code that jdk 19 will not work with higher gradle versions and there was an option to switch to gradle 7.4.2 instead.

I tried downgrading jdk, reinstalling android studio. The suggestions to switch to gradle 7.4.2 stopped after that but I am still unable to figure out what's the issue in the android level build.gradle file.

The full error message:

The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
Could not open init generic class cache for initialization script 'C:...\User\globalStorage\redhat.java\1.18.0\config_win\org.eclipse.osgi\53\0.cp\gradle\init\init.gradle'.
BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 64